# Vulkan renders only one out of two meshes

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have a problem with Vulkan. I want to render two copies of the same cube so I translate them to a different position as I show in the function `VulkanRenderer::initUniformBuffer()`. But I can only see the first cube. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I tried to change the offset in `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets()` but it did not change anything. Maybe something is wrong with my descriptors? Or I missed to set something else.

I have two uniform buffers (one per mesh), one command buffer, one pipeline and one renderpass. Here is my render loop:

```
bool VulkanRenderer::Run() {
    InitSemaphore(&_semaphoreA);
    if(_window != nullptr) {
        _window->UpdateWindow();

        auto res = VK_SUCCESS;

        InitRenderPass(_imageKHRindex);

        vkCmdBindPipeline(_commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, GetPipeline());

        const VkDeviceSize offsets [1] = { 0 };

        VkMemoryRequirements memoryRequirements;
        vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(_deviceHandler, _uniformDataBuffer, &memoryRequirements);

        VkMemoryAllocateInfo memoryAllocatorInfo {};
        memoryAllocatorInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;

        memoryAllocatorInfo.allocationSize = memoryRequirements.size;

        uint32_t memoryTypeCount = _memoryProperties.memoryTypeCount;
        for(uint32_t i = 0; i < memoryTypeCount; ++i) {
            if((memoryRequirements.memoryTypeBits & 1) == 1) {
                if((_memoryProperties.memoryTypes [i].propertyFlags &
                   VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT) == VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT) {
                    memoryAllocatorInfo.memoryTypeIndex = i;
                }
            }
            memoryRequirements.memoryTypeBits >>= 1;
        }

        vkCmdBindVertexBuffers(_commandBuffer, 0, 1, &_vertexBuffer, offsets);
        vkCmdSetViewport(_commandBuffer, 0, 1, &_viewport);
        VkRect2D rect2d;
        rect2d.extent.width = _winWidth;
        rect2d.extent.height = _winHeight;
        rect2d.offset.x = 0;
        rect2d.offset.y = 0;
        vkCmdSetScissor(_commandBuffer, 0, 1, &rect2d);

        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            const uint32_t offset = i * sizeof(_mvp);

            vkCmdBindDescriptorSets(_commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS, GetPipelineLayout(),
                                    0, 1, _descriptorSets.data(), 0, 0);

            vkCmdDraw(_commandBuffer, vertices.size(), 2, 0, 0);
        }

        vkCmdEndRenderPass(_commandBuffer);

        prePresentBarrier.image = GetSwapchainImage() [_imageKHRindex];

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(_commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_ALL_COMMANDS_BIT,
                             VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &prePresentBarrier);

        const VkCommandBuffer cmdBufs [] = { _commandBuffer };


        VkPipelineStageFlags pipelineStageFlags = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT;
        vkResetFences(_deviceHandler, 1, &_drawFence);

        VkSubmitInfo submitInfo [1] = {};
        submitInfo [0].pNext = NULL;
        submitInfo [0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
        submitInfo [0].waitSemaphoreCount = 1;
        submitInfo [0].pWaitSemaphores = &_semaphoreA;
        submitInfo [0].pWaitDstStageMask = &pipelineStageFlags;
        submitInfo [0].commandBufferCount = 1;
        submitInfo [0].pCommandBuffers = cmdBufs;
        submitInfo [0].signalSemaphoreCount = 0;
        submitInfo [0].pSignalSemaphores = NULL;

        ErrorCheck(vkEndCommandBuffer(_commandBuffer));
        ErrorCheck(vkQueueSubmit(_queue, 1, submitInfo, _drawFence));

        VkPresentInfoKHR present {};
        present.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PRESENT_INFO_KHR;
        present.swapchainCount = 1;
        present.pSwapchains = pGetVulcanSwapchainKHR();
        present.pImageIndices = &_imageKHRindex;

        do {
            res = vkWaitForFences(_deviceHandler, 1, &_drawFence, VK_TRUE, UINT64_MAX);
        } while(res == VK_TIMEOUT);

        assert(res == VK_SUCCESS);
        ErrorCheck(vkQueuePresentKHR(_queue, &present));

        ExecuteBeginCommandBuffer();

        return _window->isOpened();
    }

    ExecuteBeginCommandBuffer();
    return true;
}
```

and the `initUniformBuffer()` function:

```
void VulkanRenderer::initUniformBuffer() {

    float fov = glm::radians(45.0f);
    if(_winWidth > _winHeight) {
        fov *= static_cast<float>(_winHeight) / static_cast<float>(_winWidth);
    }

    _projection = glm::perspective(fov, static_cast<float>(_winWidth) / static_cast<float>(_winHeight), 0.1f, 100.0f);

    vulkanCamera.cameraPosition = glm::vec3(5, 3, 10);

    _view = glm::lookAt(vulkanCamera.cameraPosition,//Camera Position,
                        glm::vec3(0, 0, 0), // look at
                        glm::vec3(0, -1, 0) /*head up */);
    _model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    // Vulkan clip space has inverted Y and half Z.
    _clip = glm::mat4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                      0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                      0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f,
                      0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

    _mvp = _clip * _projection * _view * _model;

    _model = glm::translate(_model, glm::vec3(4, 4, 4));

    glm::mat4 mvp2 = _clip * _projection * _view * _model;

    //Create uniform buffer

    VkBufferCreateInfo uniformBufferCreateInfo {};
    uniformBufferCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
    uniformBufferCreateInfo.usage = VK_BUFFER_USAGE_UNIFORM_BUFFER_BIT;
    uniformBufferCreateInfo.size = sizeof(_mvp) * 2;
    uniformBufferCreateInfo.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
    uniformBufferCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    ErrorCheck(vkCreateBuffer(_deviceHandler, &uniformBufferCreateInfo, NULL, &_uniformDataBuffer));

    VkMemoryAllocateInfo memoryAllocatorInfo {};
    memoryAllocatorInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_MEMORY_ALLOCATE_INFO;

    VkMemoryRequirements memoryRequirements;
    vkGetBufferMemoryRequirements(_deviceHandler, _uniformDataBuffer, &memoryRequirements);

    memoryAllocatorInfo.allocationSize = memoryRequirements.size;

    uint32_t memoryTypeCount = _memoryProperties.memoryTypeCount;
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < memoryTypeCount; ++i) {
        if((memoryRequirements.memoryTypeBits & 1) == 1) {
            if((_memoryProperties.memoryTypes [i].propertyFlags &
               VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT) == VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT) {
                memoryAllocatorInfo.memoryTypeIndex = i;
            }
        }
        memoryRequirements.memoryTypeBits >>= 1;
    }

    ErrorCheck(vkAllocateMemory(_deviceHandler, &memoryAllocatorInfo, nullptr, &_uniformBufferMemory));

    uint8_t *pData;
    ErrorCheck(vkMapMemory(_deviceHandler, _uniformBufferMemory, 0, memoryRequirements.size, 0, (void **) &pData));

    memcpy(pData, &mvp2, sizeof(_mvp));
    memcpy(pData + sizeof(_mvp), &_mvp, sizeof(_mvp));

    vkUnmapMemory(_deviceHandler, _uniformBufferMemory);
    ErrorCheck(vkBindBufferMemory(_deviceHandler, _uniformDataBuffer, _uniformBufferMemory, 0));

    _uniformDescriptorInfo.buffer = _uniformDataBuffer;
    _uniformDescriptorInfo.offset = 0;
    _uniformDescriptorInfo.range = VK_WHOLE_SIZE;
}
```

`initDescritorSet()` function:

```
void VulkanRenderer::initDescriptorSet() {
    VkDescriptorSetAllocateInfo descriptorSetAllocateInfo [1];
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo [0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTOR_SET_ALLOCATE_INFO;
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo [0].pNext = NULL;
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo [0].descriptorPool = _descriptorPool;
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo [0].descriptorSetCount = 1;
    descriptorSetAllocateInfo [0].pSetLayouts = _descriptorSetLayout.data();

    _descriptorSets.resize(1);

    ErrorCheck(vkAllocateDescriptorSets(_deviceHandler, descriptorSetAllocateInfo, _descriptorSets.data()));

    VkWriteDescriptorSet writes [2];

    writes [0] = {};
    writes [0].sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_WRITE_DESCRIPTOR_SET;
    writes [0].pNext = NULL;
    writes [0].dstSet = _descriptorSets [0];
    writes [0].descriptorCount = 1;
    writes [0].descriptorType = VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER;
    writes [0].pBufferInfo = &_uniformDescriptorInfo;
    writes [0].dstArrayElement = 0;
    writes [0].dstBinding = 0;

    vkUpdateDescriptorSets(_deviceHandler,  1, writes, 0, nullptr);

}
```

Comment: "*one is translate and one not*" What does that mean?

Comment: I wan to render 2 identical cubes so to see then both I must move(translate) second one.

Comment: Right. So either you're translating both of them, just to different positions. Or you changing pipelines between rendering them, where one performs translation and the other does not. Or you're doing something else entirely. Which is it? Describe the approach you're taking to accomplish this.

Comment: I simply  create 2 uniforms, and in the function where I create uniforms I translate them to different position by gml::translate and then copy the models matrix to vkDeviceMemory as it is shown above in VulkanRenderer::initUniformBuffer() function. Should I set it somewhere else too?

Comment: I try to change offset in render loop in vkCmdBindDescriptorSets but it did not change anything

Comment: So edit your question to add that information to it. And restructure the question so that this is the focus of the question; don't just stick it at the end, buried under a bunch of code.

Comment: ok I edited question

Comment: It is not immediately obvious to me, that the second mesh is within the camera frustum.